# How to check if values in the Dictionary are distinct

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check if values present in a dictionary are distinct. Here's the scenario.

Let's say I have a `Dictionary(String, Integer)`. Values are `Int` type and I wanted to check all the values are different.

If they are same, the code can return the distinct `count` and `value`. If there are no distinct it should return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Distinct` Linq method to get the distinct set of values in `Values`. If it's count is the same as the size of the list then you know all the values are distinct:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

if(dict.Values.Distinct().Count() == dict.Count)
{
  Console.WriteLine("values are distinct");
}
```

Comment: Let's say if all the keys in the dictionary have a count of 1 so the soliton you suggested will return 1 right ?

Comment: Yes,, `Distinct().Count()` would return 1 if all the values are 1

Comment: If there are two key value pair which have same value . In this case it will return 2. What if I need to see the key for those values ?

Comment: If you have 2 key/value pairs with the same value then it will return 1.

Comment: But will I be able to get those same value's key?

Comment: @RajatPandit - It's really not clear what you are asking. Have you tried the code I posted?